# Library model with books

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a model of a book shop, much like a library (hence the title), but i'd prefer it if I could avoid having to model thousands of books and texture/color them. In the end I want to export the model to unity3d.

Is there a way I can model the library without having to model each individual book?

I saw another post a little like mine, but it was about textures and I don't know if I can do it in the same way. (Plus I didn't really understand it)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blender+addon+bookshelf

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped a lot. Didn't know you could get an add-on...